# Preencher o nome mesmo caso o nome não existir na tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Como eu posso substituir o trecho abaixo, para que venha o nome das atividades da `tbl_atividades_por_dep`, mesmo se o registro não existir na `tbl_atividades`,
o primeiro `select` com `distinct` é o que retorna o nome das atividades.

No segundo `select` caso o `tipo_atividade` não existir ele não retorna o nome da atividade como na primeira query.

> AND tipo_atividade IN ('RECALCULOS
>   TRIBUTOS','REAPURAÇÕES','PARCELAMENTOS','RETIFICAÇÕES SPED','INFORMES
>   GERENCIAIS','ATENDIMENTO FISCALIZAÇÃO')

```
SELECT DISTINCT atividade 
FROM tbl_atividades_por_dep AS a
WHERE atividade IN ('RECALCULOS TRIBUTOS','REAPURAÇÕES','PARCELAMENTOS','RETIFICAÇÕES SPED','INFORMES GERENCIAIS','ATENDIMENTO FISCALIZAÇÃO')

SELECT tipo_atividade,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DT_VENCIMENTO) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(DT_FIM) = MONTH(CURDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS este_mes,
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(DT_VENCIMENTO) = MONTH(CURDATE())-1 AND MONTH(DT_FIM) = MONTH(CURDATE())-1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mes_passado
FROM tbl_atividades
WHERE departamento = 'FISCAL' AND empresa_origem = 'MATRIZ'
AND tipo_atividade IN ('RECALCULOS TRIBUTOS','REAPURAÇÕES','PARCELAMENTOS','RETIFICAÇÕES SPED','INFORMES GERENCIAIS','ATENDIMENTO FISCALIZAÇÃO')
AND (STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO' OR STATUS = 'CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO')
AND YEAR(DT_VENCIMENTO) = YEAR(CURDATE())
AND YEAR(DT_FIM) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY tipo_atividade
```

Comment: Não percebi muito bem a sua questão, no entanto, penso que o seu problema está na condição tipo_atividade IN... uma das soluções poderá ser aplicar um left join

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o comando `CASE WHEN` em sua consulta.

O mesmo basicamente irá preencher com o valor que você quiser, caso sua coluna esteja com determinado valor.

```
SELECT 
      (CASE WHEN COLUNA IS NULL 
            THEN 'ATIVIDADE' 
            ELSE COLUNA END)  AS ATIVIDADE 
  FROM tbl_atividades
```